# AngularJS obscuation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, minify

I am trying to minimize/obfuscate my angular code and I am having an issue.
I read "Note on minification" here http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05
but I am defining my controllers as follows

```
directive('itemlist', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: { apicall: '=', editable: '=', viewtype: '=', selectable: '=' },
        controller: function ($scope, $http, $resource, $timeout, fileReader, framewidth, $dialog, errormsg) {
     //Code
    }
  }
}
```

How do I modifie the way I inject dependencies into the controller to allow it to be minimizable?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to minify or obfuscate? They're not the same thing. Obfuscation might add code to make it harder to read.

Comment: directive('itemlist', x=function () {... then x.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'] (or whatever)

Comment: @FritsvanCampen for now I want it to pass through google closure (http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) and come out working. But the ultimate goal is obfuscation so I am open to suggestions.

Comment: I use Google Closure Compiler myself, it's awesome. I don't know about obfuscation though, it can only hurt performance. Why do you want obfuscate?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I have some stuff there that I'd rather wasn't very obvious. But it's not too important, minification is fine. How do I modify my code so it comes out of Google Closure properly working?

Comment: @dandavis Could you elaborate a bit? I am new to angular. Is x now the controller for that directive? Where does all the `restrict`, `scope` and other possible options go?

Comment: do yourself a favor and pull nthe function out of the parens, naming it as a variable you can put in the parens. then you add a property to the function itself called $inject. fake ex: window.alert.$inject=["window"];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you have to define the controller to get it to work with minificators in my example

```
directive('itemlist', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: { apicall: '=', editable: '=', viewtype: '=', selectable: '=' },
    controller: ['$scope', '$http', '$resource', '$timeout', 'fileReader', 'framewidth', '$dialog', 'errormsg', function ($scope, $http, $resource, $timeout, fileReader, framewidth, $dialog, errormsg) {
 //Code
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i am away you can't obfuscate angular code unless the obfuscater has a option to disable obfuscating names, because the nature of angular's dependency injection if the names are obfuscated it won't work, you should be fine minifing it though. I am pretty sure google closure compiler doesn't have the name disable option, some others do though.

PS: I have tried obfuscating angular before and it only works if you disable obfuscating names, I can't remember the site that allows that though.